# Listing categories on a wordpress page

Tags: categories

I've been looking for a way to display categories on a wordpress page.
I came across the wp_list_categories function which works, but the only downside is that I have a bunch of categories and don't want them all to display vertically one by one.
Is there a way to change the display? For instance, horizontally instead?

Comment: Yes there is you can call them 'get_terms' function, please follow this link for more details https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: CSS is great for styling HTML markup. That also includes positioning characteristics.  http://www.csszengarden.com/

Answer (score 0):

FOR : category display horizontally.
This code put into the function.php file. Create a function for list of category.

```
    function category_name(){
    $cat = get_terms(array('taxonomy'=>'category'));
    echo '<div clss="design">';
    foreach($cat as $ca){
        echo '<span>';
        echo $ca->name.'&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo '</span>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
   }
```

After put this code call the function `echo category_name();` when you get the list of category.